# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.BulkImport, Version=2.0.0.0

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015, nuget, azure-cosmosdb

At the runtime, I keep running into this issue:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.BulkImport, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies.

I believe BulkImport comes from the BulkExecutor package, and I can find BulkExecutor package in `packages.config`:

```xml
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.BulkExecutor" version="1.1.0" targetFramework="net462" />
```

But I cannot find the `Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.BulkImport` mentioned in neither `packages.config` nor `app.config`.

I can, however, find `Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.BulkImport.dll` in 
`\src\packages\Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.BulkExecutor.1.1.0\lib\net451\`

and this is referenced in `.csproj` file.

I tried clearing the bin folder, clean/build project, uninstalling and reinstalling BulkExecutor library, rebooting Visual Studio 2015, but did not work.

I'm using VS 2015, Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.BulkExecutor v.1.1.0, .NET Framework v.4.6.2, Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB v.2.0.0 and Newtonsoft.Json v.10.0.2.

Comment: Hi friend, any update for this issue? Does it persist :)

Answer (score 1):

> But I cannot find the Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.BulkImport mentioned in
>   neither packages.config nor app.config.

Download the [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.BulkExecutor/1.1.0), rename it to `microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.bulkexecutor.1.1.0.zip` then you can check the content.

You'll find the `Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.BulkImport.dll` is part of the `Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.BulkExecutor` nuget package. When you reference the `Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.BulkExecutor` package in `packages.config` file, you're actually referencing the `Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.BulkImport.dll`.

And as I know, the normal Hintpath for `packages.config` format in `xx.csproj` should be something like:

```
<HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.BulkExecutor.1.1.0\lib\net451\Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.BulkImport.dll</HintPath>
```

> At the runtime, I keep running into this issue:

So the compile and build succeeded, this issue only occur in runtime? If so, please check whether the `Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.BulkImport.dll` is in your output folder.(Usually bin folder).

For your error message, maybe your assembly can't find the `Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.BulkImport.dll` it referenced if the assembly wasn't copied to output folder.You can click the `Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.BulkImport.dll` in `Solution Explorer`, then set **Copy Local** to true in `Properties Window`.

If the issue persists though the `Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.BulkImport.dll` and your assembly or executable are in same folder, maybe you have a similar situation like [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50223799/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-azure-documents-client-azure-table). The issue could result from your code, it'll be better if you could share some simple code in your question to reproduce it.